# Adjustable Locking sliding

Tags: mechanisms

I have a siding mechanism with a pipe inside of a cube. The cube can be hollow or have a hole that is about equal to the diameter of the pipe. The goal is to have the pipe lock to a specific height and be able to be adjusted to any height. A pneumatic piston will adjust the height of the pipe. The main issue is keeping the height locked, while still being able to adjust it to any height (I can't use height pints). For reference in the drawings down below, the pipe is free to move up and down. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: how much weight must the locking mechanism support? ... is this a safety lockout mechanism?

Comment: see how the sliding jaw is secured on these
...  https://duckduckgo.com/?q=bar+clamp&iax=images&ia=images

Answer (score 0):

A couple of methods;

1. a collet with locking nut
2. a split ring or collar with a locking bolt

It depends if you need to be remote with a controlled mechanism or you will be doing the locking, but either can be engineered to suit.

Comment: Thanks! I looked into those and they have really good potential. In your opinion what would you recommended if I need to have about 100 of these blocks and 20 adjusting mechanism and I don't have much money. I have unlimited access and resources to 2 resin machines, 3d printers, and a laser engraver.